# Change the currency to a currency formatter

Tags: kotlin, currency, number-formatting, decimalformat, currency-formatting

I have the following method to build a currency formatter. There are 2 input fields, the locale and the currency:

```
    private fun getCurrencyDecimalFormat(locale: Locale, currency: Currency): DecimalFormat {
        val currencyFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale) as DecimalFormat
        currencyFormat.positivePrefix = currencyFormat.positivePrefix + " "
        currencyFormat.roundingMode = RoundingMode.DOWN 
        val symbol = currency.getSymbol(locale)
        val decimalFormatSymbols = currencyFormat.decimalFormatSymbols
        decimalFormatSymbols.currencySymbol = symbol
        currencyFormat.decimalFormatSymbols = decimalFormatSymbols
        currencyFormat.isParseBigDecimal = true
        return currencyFormat
    }
```

And it is called like this:

```
    val currencyFormat = getCurrencyDecimalFormat(locale, currency)
    return currencyFormat.format(amount)
```

It works fine when the currency input is the same as the currency of the locale input, so:

- locale: es_ES, currency: EUR = 0,00 € -> OK
- locale: en_US, currency: USD = $ 0.00 -> OK

But if we have the following it is wrong:

- locale: es_ES, currency: USD = 0,00 $ -> KO
- locale: en_US, currency: EUR = $ 0.00 -> KO

It seems the currency is not set properly... any idea? I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be due to this line:

```
currencyFormat.positivePrefix = currencyFormat.positivePrefix + " "
```

Positive prefix at this point depends on the currency of the passed locale. If, for example, you invoke your method as `getCurrencyDecimalFormat(Locale.US, Currency.getInstance("EUR"))`, then your `currencyFormat` is bound to USD at this point (and `currencyFormat.positivePrefix` results in `$`).

Move this line further down, below setting your format symbols. But TBH I'm not even sure why you need it. Having a space after the currency symbol should be locale-dependent and not hardcoded.

```
fun getCurrencyDecimalFormat(locale: Locale, currency: Currency): DecimalFormat {
    val currencyFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale) as DecimalFormat

    currencyFormat.roundingMode = RoundingMode.DOWN

    val symbol = currency.getSymbol(locale)
    val decimalFormatSymbols = currencyFormat.decimalFormatSymbols

    decimalFormatSymbols.currencySymbol = symbol

    currencyFormat.decimalFormatSymbols = decimalFormatSymbols
    currencyFormat.isParseBigDecimal = true
    currencyFormat.positivePrefix = currencyFormat.positivePrefix + " "

    return currencyFormat
}
```